# What does number after semicolon mean in Nodejs error message?

Tags: node.js

If there is a type error in Nodejs at line 300 of app.js for example. The error message in the console will show up as

> TypeError: Cannot read property  at postMovement
>   (C:\Users\David\app.js:300:94)

300 is the line where there is the error message. What does the 94 at the end mean?

Comment: column. It's 94 characters into the line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It represents the column i.e. line 300 column 94